# Connecting Cloud based micro-service to local DB (not on Cloud)

Tags: cloud, mariadb, spring-cloud, spring-rest, cloud-foundry

I am creating a REST based Service, which needs to connect to DB. We cannot use cloud based DB services because of data confidentiality. Is there a way to connect to Local DB server from Cloud based Micro- Service. I am using Pivotal Cloud Foundry as PaaS and Spring Cloud for creating my application. I want to use Maria DB as relational DB. Please help and share if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create `cf cups` command to create [user provided service instance](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html). In that you have to provide DB connections and bind with your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I am getting this right, I need to create User Provided Service instance with url, username and password. And in my application, I need to use spring cloud-connectors to create data source from service. Please correct me If I am wrong.